# Can :checked and :nth-child() be used Together?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a list of checkboxes. The user can only select 10. I want to highlight the 11th (and greater) checked checkboxes *with CSS* to show they have to uncheck some. (I know there are other ways to do this including with JS and I understand the browser limitations; *this is an exercise*)

Checked checkbox labels are highlighted green, thusly:

```
li > input:checked + label {
  color: green;
}
```

The 11th and greater checkbox label should be highlighted red:

```
li > input:checked:nth-child(n+11) + label {
  background-color: red;
}
```

But this does not work. A simple test shows that I at least have the nth-child() syntax correct:

```
li:nth-child(n+11) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

That works. Is there an issue using it with `:checked` or the `+` selector?

**Edit: Fleshed out example with HTML**

Here is what the HTML *could* look like:

```
<form action="#" method="get">
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="checks1" name="checks"> <label for="checks3">Test 1</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="checks2" name="checks"> <label for="checks3">Test 2</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="checks3" name="checks"> <label for="checks3">Test 3</label></li>
        <!-- etc -->
    </ul>
</form>
```

Here is a working JS fiddle with all scenarios above: http://jsfiddle.net/eQuEW/1/

In this example the first 12 boxes have been checked. Checked check boxes have *green* labels. Checkboxes 11 and up have *bold* text just as an example of what I'm talking about. Check box 11 and 12 *should* have a red background (but they do not). Then if, for example, the user were to de-select checkbox 1, the red background would no longer be on checkbox 11 as 2-11 represent the first 10 *checked* checkboxes and 12 represents the first one greater than 10 (and, therefore, in error).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 11th and greater. Do you simply mean "the rest"? What if in a 20-item list, I check the *last 10* checkboxes? Or do you mean I can only check the *first 10* checkboxes?

Comment: Does `input:nth-child(n+11):checked` change anything? Not sure if it does (or should) but it looks more logical to me.

Comment: @BoltClock: The way i read it is, you can check up to 10 boxes.  First 10, last 10, every other one, whatever you like.  If there are more than 10 boxes checked, though, the 11th checked box (and every checked box after it) should have a red label.

Comment: The [code sample](http://sscce.org/) is incomplete, so the issue isn't reproducible. Please edit the question and add the minimal necessary code to make the sample complete.

Comment: For "11th and greater", do you want to count only checked checkboxes, or all checkboxes?

Comment: @cHao: In that case I don't believe the `:nth-*()` pseudo-classes work that way...

Comment: @cHao is correct, I'm interested in counting only the checked checkboxes. I provided a small sample and a complete jsfiddle to illustrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a bit late to the party, but since all the other answers say it can't be done in CSS alone, here is the solution.

You can only do this if all the checkboxes are in the same container. So not one checkbox per list item. If you want the result to look like a list, you will have to add some more CSS.

```css
input:checked + label {
  color: green;
}

input:checked ~ input:checked ~ input:checked ~ input:checked
~ input:checked ~ input:checked ~ input:checked ~ input:checked
~ input:checked ~ input:checked ~ input:checked + label {
  color: red;
}


/* Put each checkbox on a different line */
label:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: '\000A';
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checks1" name="checks"> <label for="checks1">Test 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checks2" name="checks"> <label for="checks3">Test 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checks3" name="checks"> <label for="checks3">Test 3</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checks4" name="checks"> <label for="checks4">Test 4</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checks5" name="checks"> <label for="checks5">Test 5</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checks6" name="checks"> <label for="checks6">Test 6</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checks7" name="checks"> <label for="checks7">Test 7</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checks8" name="checks"> <label for="checks8">Test 8</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checks9" name="checks"> <label for="checks9">Test 9</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checks10" name="checks"> <label for="checks10">Test 10</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checks11" name="checks"> <label for="checks11">Test 11</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checks12" name="checks"> <label for="checks12">Test 12</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checks13" name="checks"> <label for="checks13">Test 13</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checks14" name="checks"> <label for="checks14">Test 14</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checks15" name="checks"> <label for="checks15">Test 15</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checks16" name="checks"> <label for="checks16">Test 16</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checks17" name="checks"> <label for="checks17">Test 17</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checks18" name="checks"> <label for="checks18">Test 18</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checks19" name="checks"> <label for="checks19">Test 19</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checks20" name="checks"> <label for="checks20">Test 20</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

If i'm understanding you right, your HTML looks something like

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <input type="checkbox"...>
  <label for="...">...</label>
 </li>
 <li>
  <input type="checkbox"...>
  <label for="...">...</label>
 </li>
</ul>
```

If that's the case, you have a problem.  See, CSS selectors work from the root down, and can't go in reverse.  (Selecting a node based on its children doesn't work.)  Add to that, `:nth-child` (and `:nth-of-type`, which is what i was originally going to suggest) will select nodes based on their index within the parent, which in this case is the `<li>` element.  (That means there will never be an 11th checked box as long as each one is in its own list item.)

What you'd need is something like

```
(li:has(input:checked)):nth-of-type(n+11) label {
    ...
}
```

But `:has` and the parentheses doesn't exist in CSS, and from what i hear, it probably never will.  You'll need to do this with JS.

(Edit: I had some mention of CSS that would work if you rearranged your HTML...but it turns out it didn't work.  Pseudo-classes work independently of each other, so you'd always end up selecting the 11th box if it's checked, rather than the 11th checked box.)

Comment: Because `:nth-of-type(n+11):checked` and `:checked:nth-of-type(n+11)` do the same thing.  Both apparently select the 11th and subsequent checkboxes if they're checked, rather than selecting the 11th and subsequent checked boxes.

Comment: That's weird; I wonder why.  What if you put it on the `label`?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in the CSS specs about the order of pseudo-classes making a difference.  The only stuff i'm seeing says they can either be mutually exclusive or apply equally.  You couldn't put it on the label because the label can't be "checked"...and even if you could, you'd end up running into the same issues anyway.

Comment: No; I mean `li:has(input:checked) label:nth-of-type(n+11)`.  Where is the precedence defined?

Comment: Thing is, there is no `:has` in straight CSS.  You'd pretty much have to use jQuery, or some other framework that has similar capabilities when it comes to selectors.

Comment: That's right. I meant to say `input:checked + label:nth-child(n+11)`; sorry.

Comment: @SLaks - there will never be an 11th label _in the same immediate parent_

Comment: `input:checked + label:nth-child(n+11)` would select the 11th child if it's a label and if the box immediately preceding it is checked (assuming the HTML is redone as i suggested).  You'd need `nth-of-type` instead.  But that has the same issues; the index of the element takes priority over whether it's checked.

Comment: @cHao -- it's not that it takes priority, it's that they're different selectors.  You're thinking of it as if "you have 20 inputs, you filter that to 15 with `:checked`, then take the 11th-15th with `:nth-`" where it's actually "you have 20 inputs, you filter that to 15 with `:checked` and you filter the ___original___ 20 to 10 with `:nth` and take the intersection of these two sets"

Comment: @cwolves: I figured that was the case CSSwise.  But i'm thinking about the difference between "11th box if it's checked" and "11th checked box".  Regardless of how it works, it looks like the index becomes more important than the status.

Comment: I don't know the depth of CSS but I guess I thought that `input:checked` would select only checked boxes and then adding `:nth-child(n+11)` would further narrow that down to only > 10. So I learned something today. But this still seems, at least conceptually, possible in some way.

Comment: @Josh: With CSS, nope.  The pseudo-classes work separately (one doesn't filter the other; only items that separately match all the pseudo-classes match the selector), so you'll always end up with "the 11th box if it's checked" rather than "the 11th checked box".

Comment: @cHao Thanks for the clarification. Then (just humor me), would this technically be possible if `input` could contain a `label`? I.e. `<input type="checkbox"><label>Box</label></input>` `input:checked > label:nth-child(n+11) ...`

Comment: @Josh: Nope.  In that case, the label would always be the first and only child of the input, so there'd never be an 11th label.  The inverse (`<label><input type="checkbox"></label>`) would be valid HTML, but you'd still run into the same issues.  The problem isn't the structure; it's that the pseudo-classes can't be used to filter elements before trying to match.  They always work independently (except in the case of `:not(selector)`, but the result from `:not` can't be used as a filter either).

Comment: @cHao Ah, I gotcha now. Bummer.

Comment: I'm noticing that `:nth-child()` doesn't seem to be working with checkboxes at all. I.e. `input:nth-child(n+11) { width: 25px; }` has no effect on the width of the check boxes while something like `input:checked` does work (IE, FF, Webkit). Which seems odd.

Comment: It depends on the document's structure.  If your HTML is like i mentioned, then the inputs will each be the first (or really low-numbered) child of their parent -- they'll never be the 11th.  You'd need to say `li:nth... input` instead.  Add to that, `:nth-child` goes by the index of the element among *all* of the parent's child nodes.  If you want the 11th `li` (or the 11th `input`, if you move them all into the same parent element), rather than the 11th node if happens to be an `li` (or `input`), use `:nth-of-type(n+11)`.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't possible with pure CSS no matter what the DOM structure.  The reason is that `:nth-child` and `:nth-of-type` will always select the same elements regardless of other selectors.  So `:nth-child( n+11 )` will always select *every* select box after the 10th one.  Adding another filter like `:checked` will just filter to all the checked inputs with an index > 10.

You can't filter the results of `nth-child` because it simply counts the number of previous siblings.

And just for the fun of it, to demonstrate what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/u4xxA/1/